# Asymmetry Term in the Semi-Empirical Mass Formula

Tags: nuclear-physics, binding-energy

Could someone explain to me in simple terms what the asymmetry term means and how it is derived. I don't really want a full fledged mathematical derivation, but more the basic principle and idea behind it. I have been looking at a derivation in a book, but it is proving quite difficult for me to understand. I know the concept is identical to that of Fermi-Gas model, but I haven't properly studied that, so if someone could give a quick summary of the important details, I would be really grateful

Comment: [Wikipedia has a nice explanation of the asymmetry term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-empirical_mass_formula#Asymmetry_term). Have you read this? If so, can you explain specifically what you have difficulty following.

Comment: Thank You! I looked at loads of different sources EXCEPT wikipedia, this indeed is a concise explanation